# HTTP/2 compatibility with old/ unsupported browsers

Tags: http, network-protocols, http2

How does a website behave on a client that does **not support** the HTTP/2 protocol?
Is there a backward compatibility of the server that the server falls back on HTTP/1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard webservers will handle HTTP 1.x requests just fine and reply with HTTP 1.x responses. There are just too many browsers out there that don't speak HTTP/2 yet to completely drop HTTP 1.x support from a server.